# jquery Changing content inside element stored in var

Tags: jquery

I have ....

```
var element = "<div class = 'row'> <span class = 'text'></span></div>"
```

I'd like to add some text inside the span and then append `row` to some element. I tried

```
$(element).find(".text").text("myText"); //need to append the element returned by this?
$(".myelement").append(element);
```

This doesn't work. I know this is wrong. But what's the right way of doing it?

Comment: If you haven't added the contents of `element` to somewhere in the DOM, the JQuery selectors won't be able to find it.  You will either have to do string manipulation or add it to the DOM and manipulate it from there.

Comment: It finds it fine. I can `console.log` and see the element. The text doesn't change though

Comment: Had you created elements with `var element = $('<div />', {'class' : 'row'})` it would be trivial to access any element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're changing the created jQuery wrapper, then appending the original string (which was never changed).

Instead:

```
var el = $(element);

el. 
  find(".text").
  text("myText");

el.appendTo( $(".myelement") );
```

Will append the actual, updated elements.

```js
var element = "<div class = 'row'> <span class = 'text'></span></div>"

var el = $(element);

el. 
  find(".text").
  text("myText");

el.appendTo( $(".myelement") );
```

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

span {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="myelement"></div>
```

Comment: This works great! Thanks. Would appending and then changing be the better way than this?

Comment: Likely very little difference, if any. Choose whichever version seems most readable to you.

Comment: Works great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The simple way:

```
var element = element.replace("></span>",">New content</span");
```

Answer (score 0):

`var element = "<div class = 'row'> <span class = 'text'></span></div>"
var jqueryElement = $(element);
    $(".myelement").append(jqueryElement);
    jqueryElement.find(".text").text("myText");`

This will add it to the DOM, then set the text. Mohamed-Yousef's answer won't work because he appends a string, then tries to modify a different element because he's not calling find() on the DOM element but another new element created from the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
var element = "<div class = 'row'> <span class = 'text'></span></div>";
$(".myelement").append(element).find(".text").last().text("myText");
```